# Java path is not recognized in SonarQube installation

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm installing SonarQube version 10.

I have already installed JDK 20 and set `env` variable path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin` and `SONAR_JAVA_PATH` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20`. I have also set `JAVA_HOME` path to jdk-20. Now when I run `StartSonar` in cmd, it gives me error. I'm stuck at this problem for too long. I have tried with JDK 11 as well but still the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Error message:
[image: Error]

Java --version:
[image: java version]

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Starting SonarQube...
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Append  %JAVA_HOME%\bin to PATH variable and see it works ..Also you can Confirm java path by checking  java command  from CMD

Comment: Please also consider (for future posts/[edit]): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @xerx593 no, I didnt use quotes

Comment: The name `SONAR_..._PATH` is confusing, since it expects an "executable" and no "path" (indeed))

Comment: @xerx593 I gave it path to java.exe and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The SONAR_JAVA_PATH should end with java.exe.
Try C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/install-the-server/
This page has two examples, one for Windows and one for Linux.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also changed java version to jdk-17 as specified in the link you shared.